# How to upload magento extension in Magento Connect?

Tags: magento

I want to upload my own extension in Magento connect, but i am not able to upload zip file in Magento Connect. While uploading my module error is display " Unable to save version. Disallowed extension release file type. "

Any body have any idea, so please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your extension has to be of filetype extension `.tgz` as this is prescribed in Magento. There are online tools to convert `.zip` to `.tgz` like [this site](http://www.convertfiles.com/convert/archive/ZIP-to-TGZ.html).

Also check [this manual](http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentoenterprise/images/packagingmagentoconnectextensions6%200.pdf) from Magento about how to package Magento Connect Extensions.

Comment: Still, i got a same error. Can i send you my extension zip file?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the zip file you have is not a Magento package. You can use the Magento Connect Manager to upload only valid Magento packages containing a package.xml file in the correct format, including the `<contents>` element containing the extension files.

In the case you have a package.xml file having a structure like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
    <name>...</name>
    <version>.</version>
    ...
    <contents>...</contents>
    ...
</package>
```

try to recreate the package as a .tgz file by placing the package.xml in the root and the other files in their respective places relatively to the root.

In the case you do not have a package.xml file, I would advise you to consider installing the extension manually by coping its files to their respective places in your Magento installation.